# Error when updating RCP application as featured, using P2

Tags: eclipse, p2

i have a RCP application crated with Indogo and P2 Enabled.

Excepto that I can't see the menu, automatica updates detect new version and invite me to update.

But when looks like is finishing this error shows :

```
An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=profile,     
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, 
operand=[R]ar.com.cse.balanza.core.product_root.win32.win32.x86 1.0.0 --> null, 
action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).

Backup of file C:\Temp\Deploys\AgroTrackerBalanzaProduct-1.0.0\ejecutable\jre\lib\charsets.jar failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: C:\Temp\Deploys\AgroTrackerBalanzaProduct-1.0.0\ejecutable\jre\lib\charsets.jar
```

The error tell me that something happend in the "uninstalling process", so something should happend before !?!

I'm running the application windows 7, but something similar foudn on windows xp.

Beside that I can see that jar files was downloaded (i see jar files version 1.0.1), so may be I can change some launcher configuration? I tried changing artifacs.xml, the binary launcher ... but allways use the version 1.0.0.

Any idea of what is wrong ?
Any suggestion for the work around ??

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

See [Bug 300812](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300812) - Can not update root folder jre on windows

It looks like you have to take special steps on windows to update the JRE if you distribute it with your RCP app.  The bug is not yet fixed.